# Can I use rewrite to show an alternative domain?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-masking

I'm currently trying to setup a website on free hosting, but use the "branded" URL registered with another provider. I've already tried switching NS but the free hosting NS is very restrictive (Doesn't allow TXT records).

I'm back with the URL registrar, and I've got a URL redirect to the "ugly" URL at free hosting. I've already tried to make the redirect masked, but I lose all the file names, and many meta tags due to the `<iframe>`. Also any files that aren't `.html` are served (e.g. sitemap.xml).

Is there anyway I can solve this using `.htaccess` on the free hosting side? - that's the only thing I have access to (i.e. no access to httpd)

I've tried all these "pairs" of rewrites but with no success (I'm still new at rewrites so they might not be completely correct)

```
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule "^(.*)ugly.url.com(.*)$" "$1www.my-brand-url.com$2" [L,R=302]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ugly.url.com [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.my-brand-url.com/$1 [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^ugly.url.com/(.*)$ http://www.my-brand-url.com/$1 [L,R=302]

ServerName ugly.url.com
ServerAlias www.my-brand-url.com
```

Comment: You can't use ServerName or ServerAlias in htaccess. But those are things you'll need in order for this to work as your hosting provider needs to know that it needs to server your content if it gets a request for a specific hostname

Comment: Here's one of the sites I used: [link](https://aloneonahill.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) in the summary section at the end "To redirect an old domain to a new domain:"`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old_domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new_domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]` does this mean that somewhere else there was a `ServerName, ServerAlias`pair for these. Is there any other way to achieve that - parked domains maybe?

Comment: @JonLin, here's another site: [link](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/redirect-without-changing-url)